# Java read textfile and combining different lines together

Tags: java

Lets say we have the following text file with an ID(non unique),Name, and Number

```
1 Hello 3
1 Goodbye 2
1 Hello 6
1 Goodbye 5
```

They are not on the same line and I would like to be able to add them together and put that to a variable. These would not necessary be right next to each other like this so it would need to be in a if statement if id and name are both similar then add the numbers.

I would like to be able to get this as my output

```
Hello 9
Goodbye 7
```

So it would have to read the whole file before outputting anything, how would this be done?

Comment: I suppose this can be done by writing some code

Comment: Try some code and in case of fail we will help you.

Comment: I just dont know where to start this apart from basic file reading

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File("your/file/path");
    String line = "";
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // the algorithm that YOU should develop
            //or fail to develop and ask about to group things etc.
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that uses Java 8 stream api and Java 7 NIO.2 api:

```
// read all lines from the file
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("<path_to_your_file>"))
        // begin the stream
        .stream()
        // split every line by whitespaces
        // to get arrays like [1, "Hello", 3], [1, "Goodbye", 2]...
        .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
        // collecting to a map, grouping by the String {firstColumn}-{secondColumn}
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(split -> split[0] + "-" + split[1],
                // downstream collector sums the 3rd column after parsing them as long
                Collectors.summingLong(split -> Long.parseLong(split[2]))))
        // so we have Map<String, Long> with entries like {1-Hello -> 9}, {2-Goodbye -> 7}
        .forEach((key, value) ->
                // we print these entries one each line (println)
                // by taking the part after dash of key,
                // and a space between key and value, like: Hello 9
                System.out.println(key.split("-")[1] + " " + value));
```

Please note that this solution is far from complete, for example:
1- Reads the whole file into memory so if the file is too big it can cause problem (large allocated heap, `OutOfMemoryError`s etc). Would be better if it was done by streaming.

2- If the "Name" is allowed to have whitespaces, splitting with whitespace will fail - that would need some extra work. The solution assumes every line has exactly 3 "columns", separated by whitespace.

3- If the "Name" is allowed to have dash (`-`), splitting by dash while prining the output would give incorrect result. Actually, grouping should be done using a separate classifier class, or something line a `Tuple` or `Entry`.

4- Solution assumes 3rd column is always a parseable `long`, and the sum does not go beyond the boundaries of `Long`.

But at least it can give you which steps to follow. You can do your proper implementation with similar steps.